# JavaScript (ReactJS), import from

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this component (half of the code):

App:

```
...
import LayerActivator from "../../layer-activator/LayerActivator";
import { stateIcon } from "../IconLayers";
...
export class App extends Component {
  ...

}

export default App
```

LayerActivator:

```
...
import IconLayers, {stateIcon} from "../layers/IconLayers";
...
export default class LayerActivator extends Component {
```

IconLayers:

```
export const stateIcon = {
  Marker: 1,
  Heatmap: 2,
  Cluster: 3
}

class IconLayers extends Component {
    ...
}

export default IconLayers;
```

What I want is in "App" import in 1 line `LayerActivator` and `{ stateIcon }`, because

```
`stateIcon` is defined inside `IconLayers`, 
and `IconLayers` is imported on `LayerActivator`
```

It's possible?

Comment: You could re-export `stateIcon` in your `LayerActivator` file, but honestly, you should keep everything as separated as possible to benefit from tree-shaking best results.

Comment: ...and simply import them both with 2 lines like you're doing.